# Model fit after inverse regression and forward stagewise on residuals

Tags: r, linear-regression, lars

I work with prediction of height based on genetic information.  The data is several hundred thousand data points from every organism, but a simplified version could be:

```
    dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
height = c(2, 4, 6, 10, 12), 
gene1 = c(0.2, -0.3, -0.6, 0, -0.8), 
gene2 = c(0.4, -0.2, -0.4, 0.2, -0.6)), 
gene3 = c(-0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7)
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I became interested in doing inverse regression on gene 1, since the residual values I obtain from that gives different results than using height as response. So the regression is:

```
model1 <- lm(gene1 ~ height, data=df)
```

I then take the residual values from this and do forward stagewise (LARS package) after removing gene1 from the dataframe:

```
resid <- model1$residuals
resid <- as.data.frame(resid)
Stagewise <- lars(df, resid$resid, type="forward.stagewise", max.steps=2, use.Gram=FALSE)
```

After doing this, I’m interested in fitting the model so I can get a value for height (and run the test set). Since I am using the residual values for the stagewise procedure, I am not sure how to obtain this.

Assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: you want to obtain the residual values from ```lars``` object? Sorry I really cannot follow the steps and I can't run your code since height and gene1 are not in there

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have corrected the dataframe. I am not looking for residual values from LARS object. I am looking to fit a model for predciting height after doing the inverse regression and the stagewise of residuals.

Comment: i really don't get it. it would help if you are bit more precise about what you want to regress height with. Seems like it is more statistics than programming. you can try posting on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I have tried posting it at stackexchange also. I don't think I'm able to explain this more easily.